# Protocol with typealias can't conform to type AnyObject?

Tags: swift, nsuserdefaults, swift-protocols

I'm trying to write a general way to store data to NSUserDefaults.  The problem I'm running into is that `NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setValue(value, forKey: key)` takes in type `AnyObject?` and if I set a type in a protocol, `String`, `Bool`, etc. doesn't map to `AnyObject?`, since they're not objects.  Anyway, how can I make this code work without having to implement an extension for each type?  Thanks for help!

```
protocol UserDefaultUtility {
    typealias UserDefaultType

    var key: String { get }

    func getDefault() -> UserDefaultType?
    func setDefault(value: UserDefaultType?)
    func removeDefault()
}

extension UserDefaultUtility {
    func getDefault() -> UserDefaultType? {
        return NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey(key) as? UserDefaultType
    }

    // Doesn't work-- Cannot convert value of type 'Self.UserDefaultType' to expected argument type 'AnyObject?'
    /*
    func setDefault(value: UserDefaultType) {
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setValue(value, forKey: key)
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
    }
    */

    func removeDefault() {
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().removeObjectForKey(key)
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
    }
}

// I have to do this instead to get it to work for any type I want to save to user defaults
extension UserDefaultUtility where UserDefaultType == String {
    func setDefault(value: String?) {
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setValue(value, forKey: key)
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
    }
}
```

**Edit 1**

Implemetation

```
/**
 Strings stored in UserDefaults are accessed by this utility. Note that the String in the enum header is there to tell the enum that it's raw value is a String.
*/
enum StringUserDefaulstUtility: String, UserDefaultsUtility {
    typealias UserDefaultType = String

    case UserFirstName = "userFirstName"
    case UserLastName = "userLastName"

    var key: String {
        get {
            return self.rawValue
        }
    }
}

enum NSDateUserDefaultsUtility: String, UserDefaultsUtility {
    typealias UserDefaultType = NSDate

    case TokenExpiration = "tokenExpiration"

    var key: String {
        get {
            return self.rawValue
        }
    }
}
```

Use Case

```
func someUselessFunc() {
    // Sets the user's first name
    StringUserDefaulstUtility.UserFirstName.setDefault("Matt")
    // Gets the user's first name
    StringUserDefaulstUtility.UserFirstName.getDefault()
    // Removes the user's first name
    StringUserDefaulstUtility.UserFirstName.removeDefault()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to make this code work without changing too much, you can cast the value only.

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setValue(value as? AnyObject, forKey: key)
```

However, I think you need to verify the value to conform AnyObject once you implement the protocol.

Comment: This seems to work, can you give an example of how I would have to verify the value to conform when I implement it?  You can reference my updated code and implementation.

Comment: @hoffware I think NSUserDefault only accept "Property List Types and Objects". Therefore, even typealias has to be a member of them.  https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/PropertyList.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you're misusing protocols here. You don't want to every element of a given type to have the same key, but that's how you've implemented it. Since the key is part of the protocol, and you're attaching the key as part of an extension, there can only be one key that stores strings. That doesn't seem very useful. (Maybe I'm missing the use case here; can you give an example of how you plan to use it?)

What you seem to be going for is to just make a slightly more Swifty interface to `NSUserDefaults`. That's no problem.

```
struct UserDefaults {
    static func setValue<T: AnyObject>(value: T, forKey key: String) {
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setValue(value, forKey: key)
    }
    static func valueForKey<T>(key: String) -> T? {
        return NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey(key) as? T
    }
}

UserDefaults.setValue("123", forKey: "x")
let str: String? = UserDefaults.valueForKey("x")
print(str)

UserDefaults.setValue(123, forKey: "y")
let num: Int? = UserDefaults.valueForKey("y")
print(num)
```

As a side note, [there is almost never a reason to call `synchronize()`](https://twitter.com/Catfish_Man/status/674727133017587712) on `NSUserDefaults`. It is almost exactly a sleep call. It doesn't actually "synchronize" anything.

Comment: I updated my code to include the implementation of it.  Let me know what you think of it now.  I appreciate your answer, and it's definitely valid, but I was trying to make it as concise as possible.  I don't understand why the key won't change among uses, I'm pretty sure it will?

Answer (score 0):

Since the purpose is trying to write a general way to store data to NSUserDefaults. I'm assuming you mean the generic. I suggest to try something more straightforward. Just copy & paste the following codes into playground to see the results.

```
    func getDefault(key: String) -> AnyObject? {
        return NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey(key)
    }

    func setDefault(value: AnyObject?, forKey defaultName: String) {
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setValue(value, forKey: defaultName)
    }

    func removeDefault(forKey defaultName: String) {
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().removeObjectForKey(defaultName)
    }

    //// String Example
    let key1 = "Key1"
    getDefault(key1)
    setDefault("ABC", forKey: key1)
    getDefault(key1)
    removeDefault(forKey: key1)
    getDefault(key1)

    //// Number Example
    let key2 = "Key2"
    getDefault(key2)
    setDefault(5678, forKey: key2)
    getDefault(key2)
    removeDefault(forKey: key2)
    getDefault(key2)

    //// NSDate Example
    let key3 = "Key3"
    getDefault(key3)
    setDefault(NSDate(), forKey: key3)
    getDefault(key3)
    removeDefault(forKey: key3)
    getDefault(key3)

    //// Array Example
    let key4 = "Key4"
    getDefault(key4)
    setDefault(["One", "Two", "Three", "Four"], forKey: key4)
    getDefault(key4)
    removeDefault(forKey: key4)
    getDefault(key4)

    //// Bool Example
    let key5 = "Key5"
    getDefault(key5)
    setDefault(true, forKey: key5)
    getDefault(key5)
    removeDefault(forKey: key5)
    getDefault(key5)

    //// UserDefaultType
    typealias UserDefaultType = String
    let userDefaultType: UserDefaultType = "AnyStringHere"
    let key6 = "Key6"
    getDefault(key6)
    setDefault(userDefaultType as AnyObject, forKey: key6)
    getDefault(key6)
    removeDefault(forKey: key6)
    getDefault(key6)
```